# Get the size of image in vueJs mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to get the height and the width of an image who is in the local asset folder of my project.

I try to do like in the mounted() :

```
let grid = new Image()
grid.src = require('../../assets/sprites/grid.png');
console.log(grid.naturalWidth, grid.naturalHeight)
```

But I always have 0 instead of 3030px

EDIT:

I found a half-solution because it's not complete
this.gridPattern is defined in data above,
I need to re-assign it value but , the value is 0

```
let grid = new Image()

grid.src = require('../../assets/sprites/grid_pathern.png');

grid.onload = () => {
    console.log(`the image dimensions are ${grid.width}x${grid.height}`);
    this.gridPattern = {width:grid.width,height:grid.height}
    console.log(this.gridPattern)
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to await the image to be fully loaded beforehand in order to get the width and height of an instantiated image.

```
async mounted() {
    let image = new Image();
    
    image.onload = function () {
        console.log(`the image dimensions are ${img.width}x${img.height}`);
    };
   
    image.src = require('../../assets/sprites/grid_pathern.png');
}
```

Comment: With this code , I have nothing in my console, maybe the image is not loaded ?

Comment: No 404 either in the console ? how about the network tab ?

Comment: @Seb Try `img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(require('../../assets/sprites/grid.png'));`

Comment: may be path issue, try `grid.src = require('@/assets/sprites/grid_pathern.png')` or `grid.src = require('../assets/sprites/grid_pathern.png')`

Comment: is there a way to get the size in KB?

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that you cannot query the height and width of an image without placing it in the DOM unless you have already assigned it a `height` and `width` programatically. Rather, you want to query the [*natural* height and width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth) (`naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth`), which are the image's original dimensions before being placed in the DOM. I also recommend adding anything you plan to invoke programatically to your `data` object.

```js
import MyImage from '../../assets/sprites/grid.png';

export default {
  [...],
  data() {
    return {
      myImage
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = this.myImage;
    console.log(img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
  },
  [...]
}
```